# How to get google sheets name

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

Given a url of googlesheets like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dprQgvpy-qHNU5eHDoOUf9qXi6EqwBbsYPKHB_3c/edit#gid=1139845333
How could I use gspread api to get the name of the sheet?
I mean the name may be sheet1, sheet2, etc
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the sheet names from a Google Spreadsheet from the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit#gid=1139845333`.
- From `How could I use gspread api to get the name of the sheet?`, you want to achieve this using gsperad for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dprQgvpy-qHNU5eHDoOUf9qXi6EqwBbsYPKHB_3c/edit#gid=1139845333"
spreadsheet = client.open_by_url(url)
sheet_names = [s.title for s in spreadsheet.worksheets()]
print(sheet_names)
```

- In this script, please use your `client = gspread.authorize(credentials)`.
- When this script is run, the sheet names are returned as a list.

#### References:

- [open_by_url(url)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v4.0.1/api.html?highlight=open#gspread.Client.open_by_url)
- [worksheets()](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v4.0.1/api.html?highlight=worksheets#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.worksheets)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> May I know what if I only want the sheet name of a particular one? Usually, for each additional sheet we create, it comes with a series of number at the end (gid=1139845333), I just want the name for that sheet instead of all.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dprQgvpy-qHNU5eHDoOUf9qXi6EqwBbsYPKHB_3c/edit#gid=1139845333"
gid = "1139845333"
sheet_name = [s.title for s in spreadsheet.worksheets() if str(s.id) == gid]
if len(sheet_name) == 1:
    print(sheet_name)
else:
    print("No sheet of the GID " + gid)
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Thank you for your response! May I know what if I only want the sheet name of a particular one? Usually, for each additional sheet we create, it comes with a series of number at the end (gid=1139845333), I just want the name for that sheet instead of all. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.